# Integrating in L'Hôpital

Tags: limits

According to L'Hopital

If $f(a)=0$ and $g(a)=0$ then$\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to a}} \frac {f(x)}{g(x)} $ = $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to a}} \frac {f'(x)}{g’(x)} $ so can we interpret this $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to a}} \frac {f'(x)}{g’(x)} $ = $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to a}} \frac {\int f'(x)}{\int g’(x)} $?

Comment: Integrals are not true inverse operators of derivatives.

Comment: Only if you pick the primitives of $f'$ and $g'$ such that are zero at $x=a$. For example, $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac {2x}{2x}=1$ but $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{x^2+3}{x^2+1}=3$

Comment: This is not so common but you can interpret this as : if $f(x) /g(x) \to L$ as $x\to a$ then $\int_a^x f(t) \, dt/\int_a^x g(t) \, dt\to L$ as $x\to a$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh i am wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem with your interpretation is that $\int f'(x)$ in general represent **an** antiderivative of $f'$, so it could be $f(x)$ or $f(x) +7$ or $f(x) - 5$, ...

A second problem arises from the equality of the limits. One needs to be careful with limits theorems. For example, a theorem about limits says:

- Theorem:

$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)^2 = \left(\lim_{x\to a} f(x)\right)^2$$

However, the following is false:

- Not a Theorem:

$$\left(\lim_{x\to a} f(x)\right)^2 = \lim_{x\to a} f(x)^2$$

Looks odd, right? Isn't equality supposed to be reflexive? How could happen that $a=b$ but $b\ne a$?

The point is that the theorem as I wrote it is incomplete:

- Theorem (now correctly written):

**If $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists then
$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a} f(x)^2$ exists and**

$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)^2 = \left(\lim_{x\to a} f(x)\right)^2$$

But the converse theorem is false: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a} f(x)^2$ may exists while $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ don't.

In the same way, the L'Hôpital's rule shouldn't just be written as this:

- Incorrect L'Hôpital's rule:

If $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = 0$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = 0$

then

$$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}
$$

The complete theorem reads as follows:

- L'Hôpital's rule:

If $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = 0$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = 0$ **and the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ exists**

then the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists and

$$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}
$$

but the converse is not necessarily true, this mean that you shouldn't write $$\lim_{x \to a} \frac {f'(x)}{g'(x)} = \lim_{x \to a} \frac {\int f'(x)}{\int g'(x)}$$ even if $\int f'(x)$ and $\int g'(x)$ represent the "correct" antiderivatives $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.